# Image Scale AFnetworking

Tags: ios, xcode, image, afnetworking

how can I change the size of my image display on the UIImageview, I am downloading the images with AFNETWORKING and it fits the size of the UIImageView.

But I want to show only half of the image , just like the Facebook app you see only one portion of the image click on the image view the full image . thanks

```
UIImageView *posterImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init]; 
    posterImage.frame = CGRectMake(index * showsScrollView.bounds.size.width + 50, 40, 225, 337);

    [showsScrollView addSubview:posterImage];
    // 6.5 - Asynchronously load the image        
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:posterUrl]];
    [posterImage setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"]
                                success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
                                } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] decrementActivityCount];
                                }];

    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] incrementActivityCount];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure about what you're going for, but you may be able to accomplish something similar by setting the `contentMode` property.

Otherwise, you would do any resizing you need to do in the success block.

Important side note: You don't have to manually manage `AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager` at all. Just set `enabled` to `YES` for the shared manager, and it will automatically show and hide as you make and complete requests.

Comment: I tried to set isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible in the shared manager to yes and got error "assignment to readonly property"?